# Allow users to add custom domain pointing to a subdomain in my app on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying this since last 2 days.

I build an example app using a very detailed tutorial here - https://john2x.com/blog/wildcard-certs-from-lets-encrypt-cert-manager-ingress-nginx-gke.html

What I have working right now:

I have an app running at demo-app.example.com wherein users can have their own subdomain like `john.demo-app.example.com` 
I got the wildcard certificates working as well

I have two questions now:

1 - How do I allow users to add their custom domain pointing to the subdomain in my app. When I just create a CNAME pointing to a subdomain in my app, it does not work, I think because of how the whole thing is configured.

2 - I want to move from demo-app.example.com to just example.com to the top level, so how should the DNS zone be configured for this?

Finally, given the requirements, is Kubernetes the best I could use or I would be better off using something else. It is a NodeJS app btw.

Comment: For 1, what exactly do you mean? You want users to be able to create a subdomain pointing to your app? So when you type in `subdomain.example.com` it goes to the same place as `example.com`?

Comment: @kimbo No. I want users to be able to point their own domain name (including a subdomain) to my app's subdomain: 
`johndoe.com -> john.example.com`

and also: 
`profile.johndoe.com -> john.example.com `

in other words allow them to use A Name records or CNAME records with their DNS provider to point to my app.

Comment: They can already create a CNAME record for your domain. But you can't create it for them.

Comment: yes they can, but in this particular case it is hitting my NGINX but from there it doesn't know where to go, because the ingress host is set as my domain name. how do I tell ingress to accept custom domains.
Also I am not sure how to create and manage their certificates

Comment: I am very new to this, so I might not be asking correct questions as well. I will go and read a bit more.

Comment: So are you trying to setup some kind of website hosting service?

Comment: I am trying to set up a multi-tenant platform where new users will get a subdomain when they register and afterwards they can point a custom domain to their page. something similar to shopify.com or wordpress.com

Comment: Hey, @SambhavGore did you find a solution for this? I am struggling with the same.

Comment: @Saurabh I was able to solve this however, google-cloud was looking too expensive for my needs so I set up a cluster on Digital Ocean. I don't remember everything about it right now as I did it few months ago, but in Short whenever there is a need to point to a custom domain, I add a new Ingress pointing to the same Backend Service.